# Fixing div with absolute positioning being placed under image

Tags: html, css, position

I have an image and also a small container that I want to be placed on the container, but it sets this ".innerimage" below the image.

**Do not suggest using top: xx;**   because in my actual project I have many divs with the same class and I can't use top or it will screw it up.

```
<div id="page">

    <div class="image">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Black_300.jpg">
            <div class="innerimage"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) Can you post the definition for the `innerimage` class? (2) Which `div` has the absolute positioning? Your example doesn't show any. Thanks.

Comment: More questions: (3) When you say you want the small container (which I assume is `innerimage`) to be placed on the container, do you want it to be positioned before the image or positioned as an overlay on the image? (4) Is it necessary to place the `innerimage` after the `img` element, or could you place it as the first child of `div.image`?

Comment: @James: When you have 2 minutes, can you answer the questions above, or validate the response below (if it fixes your issue), or let us know if you found a solution? By doing this you could help other people on StackOverflow. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understand your need and if you don't have to [support IE7](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table), maybe you could use the `display:table` and `display:table-caption`

I updated the JSFiddle with these CSS properties:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZhdMj/1/